# In Branch.io how to get the "link data" in webhook system?

Tags: deep-linking, webhooks, branch.io

I build a link in branch.io appending a query parameters like this:

http://bnc.lt/a/?action=z&storeGroupId=xxx&storeId=yyy&identity=abc

this link has 3 custom deep link parameters (action, storeGroupId and StoreId)

and an identity parameter.

Everything works fine but in the webhook system the "link data" (in session_referring_link_data) was empty. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch links consider appended parameters (`action=z&storeGroupId=xxx&storeId=yyy&identity=abc`) to be *query parameters* instead of *deep link data*. When the app opens from a click with the query parameters, query parameters associated with the link click are merged with any deep link data associated with the link and passed through to the app.

I've just made a pull request to include link click query parameters inside the webhook post. You should see them start to appear in the post body in the next few days as `session_referring_click_query`.

In the mean time, you can embed those query parameters into the deep link data by embedding them into a JSON and stringifying it, then appending the query parameter: `?data=base64encodedparams`. It's listed as option 6 [here](https://dev.branch.io/link_creation_guide/#appending-query-parameters).